# Yii2 ModelSearch ordering issue

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have created a model and model search using gii/crud which is mostly working great. I like how it allows you to sort or filter the records by specifying parameters in the URL without needing to write any additional code. Example:

`http://domain.com/api/user/index?sort=created_at`

However, what I can't find how to order the records in either an ascending or descending order in the URL. I can't find any examples of this.

I feel like I should be able to add another paramater (such as order) like:

`http://domain.com/api/user/index?sort=created_at&order=DESC`

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I have looked through the Yii source code and believe that to have a descending order you need to prefix the attribute with a minus/dash. Such as `?sort=-created_at`. However this then breaks the SQL elsewhere. Still digging...

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html will help you

Comment: @Saurabh; Yes, I read that but that method requires manually adding code. I am trying to learn to use the default Yii capabilities for this.

Comment: not getting what exactly you need..

Comment: I gave an answer then I removed it as I didn't see your comment. You already did figure it out. any [Data Provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#active-data-provider) in Yii should be using a [yii\data\Sort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html) instance to handle sorting which should support descending sort within a minus sign as shown in its [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/56400add978427156673947e3c3d389674c93b56/framework/data/Sort.php#L247). also note that you can chain sorting like `?sort=-created_at,id,-name`

Comment: Maybe you are just looking for default ordering for initial loading of the results: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-data-providers.md

Comment: Thanks @SalemOuerdani. However by adding the `-` I receive the error that `column -created_at doesn't exist`. I feel that there's a bug in Yii but I haven't been able to track it down yet.

Comment: To add to the last comment:  The query being generated is `SELECT * FROM 'news_item' ORDER BY '-created_at', 'created_at' DESC LIMIT 20`. This is from a request of `http://domain.com/news-item?sort=-created_at`

Answer (score 0):

In your search model, define the $query variable like below for descending

```
$query = Modelname::find()->orderBy('created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I need to answer my own question. I realise now it may have been more helpful if I described what I was doing in more detail.

I am building a RESTful API and had overridden the news-item index method so I can use ActiveDataProvider to have more control over the query. In doing this it broke the default sorting method (descending only).

By default, the RESTful API will allow you to add `?sort=created_at` for ascending and `?sort=-created_at` for descending order. However the construction of the SQL when overriding the builtin action prevents this from working properly.

Edit: I just realised that I broke it by trying to include my own sort method which conflicted with the default. Once I removed my sort, it works as expected.